# JQuery Draggable stops working inside updatepanel after a postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an asp.net updatepanel with some devexpress controls inside it.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upInsertPartNumber" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <div id="divSAFRReceivingPanel" style="width: 50%; position: fixed;">          
             <dx:ASPxFormLayout runat="server" ID="frmControlPanel" AlignItemCaptionsInAllGroups="True">
                    ...  textbox here
                    ...  submit button here
             </dx:ASPxFormLayout>
         </div>
```

There's also a div that I have attached the jquery draggable behavior to.  When it first loads up, it works fine.  As soon as I submit the form, though, the div gets set to its original position and loses its draggability.

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    ResetPanel();
});

function ResetPanel() {
    $('#divSAFRReceivingPanel').draggable({ revert: 'false' });             
}
```

Ideally, I want to have the draggable div to maintain its position and draggability even after the form has been submitted.  Any thoughts on how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: The form is submitting via ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's because when you *raise* an event **a postback ocurrs**, and **only the content in the UpdatePanel is refreshed**, so, your elements *lose* the functionality they have before the postback.

What you can do is:

- To keep track of the div's position before the postback
- When the postback ocurrs send some javascript from the server side (C#) to the client side (the browser), maybe like this

  ```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ResetPanelWithPosition();", funcCall);
  ```
- Create a function `ResetPanelWithPosition()` that re-attach the draggable behavior and set the last position you store in the first step.